# copy values/rows from a file which are within special characters

Tags: text-processing

I have a file which looks like this

```
@
0 60
0 60
0 1
0 1
0 3
0 0
@
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
@
.
.
.
@
```

and from this I want to create file1 with the values/rows from the first @ to the second @ and then a next file2 with the values/rows from the second @ to the third @
so the file 1 should have the following output

```
0 60
0 60
0 1
0 1
0 3
0 0
```

file 2 should have the following output

```
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `csplit` is for. With the GNU implementation:

```
csplit -f file --suppress-matched -z input.txt '/^@/' '{*}'
```

Comment: Quite correct unix. If only I had such knowlwdge. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As primitive as possible:

```
i=0; while read NN; do if [[ $NN == "@" ]] ;then i=$(($i+1)) ; else echo $NN >> file$i; fi done < file
```

Hi

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk :

```
awk -v 'f=file' '/^@/{i++;close(f i);fg=1;next}!fg{next}{print > f i}' infile
```

If you want only 2 files :

```
awk -v 'f=file' -v 'nb=2' '/^@/{i++;close(f i);fg=1;next}!fg{next}i>nb{exit}{print > f i}' infile
```